# can not add two multiplications result in text box in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sir 
i have 7 text boxes .1st two take values from user and display the multiplication result on 3rd text box when it clicked.4th and 5th textboxes also take values and display the multiplication result in 6th text box when it clicked.now 7th textbox will display the addition result when it clicked.7th textbox takes the values from 3rd and 6th textbox.
my problem is that i can not do the addition and cant display the result in 7th text box in html and jscript.plz help me.....i am attached the code...

```
 <html>
  <script>
   function getText1(){
      var in1=document.getElementById('in1').value;
      var in2=document.getElementById('in2').value;


      var tot1=parseInt(in1)*parseInt(in2); 


      document.getElementById('tot1').value=tot1;
   }


   function getText2(){


      var in1=document.getElementById('in3').value;
      var in2=document.getElementById('in4').value; 

      var tot2=parseInt(in1)*parseInt(in2);           

      document.getElementById('tot2').value=tot2;
   }

   function gt1(){

   var in1=document.getElementById('tot1').value; 
   var in2=document.getElementById('tot2').value;

   var gt1=parseInt(in1)+parseInt(in2);
   document.getElementById('gt').value = gt1;



  </script>

 <form>
 <input type="text"id="in1"/>
 <input type="text" id="in2"/>
 <input type="text" onclick="getText1()" id="tot1"/>
 <br>
 <input type="text"id="in3"/>
 <input type="text" id="in4"/>
 <input type="text" onclick="getText2()" id="tot2"/>
  <br>
 <input type="text" onclick="gt1()" id="gt1"/>

</form>
</html>
```

Comment: It has to be `document.getElementById('gt1').value=gt1;` (`gt1` instead of `gt`).

Comment: bt still not working...plz help

Comment: some one plz help me....

Comment: relplace this code   document.getElementById('gt1').value = gt1;

Answer (score 1):

There are several problem

1). Element `id` is one line is incorrect. It should be:

```
document.getElementById('gt1').value = gt1;
```

2). `result` variable is undefined. It should be:

```
if (!isNaN(gt1))
```

3). `onclick="gt1()"` will not work (because there is id with the same name `gt1`). Use, for example:

```
function getText3() { ... }
```

and

```
<input type="text" onclick="getText3()" id="gt1"/>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZXMe/12/).

**Update**. Ok, I didn't notice that you want multiplication, but somewhy had written `+` in `getText1()` and `getText2()` functions. Then you should also replace these two `+` with `*`:

[Multiplication fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZXMe/13/).

Comment: @ArghaGuhaRoy if by "not working" you were talking about replacing `+` with `*` - I have done this in updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <script>
   function getText1(){
      var in1=document.getElementById('in1').value;
      var in2=document.getElementById('in2').value;


      var tot1=parseInt(in1)*parseInt(in2); 


      document.getElementById('tot1').value=tot1;
   }


   function getText2(){


      var in1=document.getElementById('in3').value;
      var in2=document.getElementById('in4').value; 

      var tot2=parseInt(in1)*parseInt(in2);           

      document.getElementById('tot2').value=tot2;
   }

   function gt(){

   var in1=document.getElementById('tot1').value; 
   var in2=document.getElementById('tot2').value;

   var gt1=parseInt(in1)+parseInt(in2);
   document.getElementById('gt1').value = gt1;
}


  </script>

 <form>
 <input type="text"id="in1"/>
 <input type="text" id="in2"/>
 <input type="text" onclick="getText1()" id="tot1"/>
 <br>
 <input type="text"id="in3"/>
 <input type="text" id="in4"/>
 <input type="text" onclick="getText2()" id="tot2"/>
  <br>
 <input type="text" onclick="gt()" id="gt1"/>

</form>
</html>
```

use this code  it is working. and compare with own code. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined 'result' variable
and in 'gt1()' :

```
document.getElementById('gt').value = gt1;
```

1- There is no 'gt' element in the page

2- 'gt1' should renamed to 'result'
and at the end code will be:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getText1() {
        var in1 = document.getElementById('in1').value;
        var in2 = document.getElementById('in2').value;
        var tot1 = parseInt(in1) + parseInt(in2);
        document.getElementById('tot1').value = tot1;
    }
    function getText2() {
        var in1 = document.getElementById('in3').value;
        var in2 = document.getElementById('in4').value;
        var tot2 = parseInt(in1) + parseInt(in2);
        document.getElementById('tot2').value = tot2;
    }

    function gt1() {
        var in1 = document.getElementById('tot1').value;
        var in2 = document.getElementById('tot2').value;
        var result = parseInt(in1) + parseInt(in2);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('gt1').value = result;
        }
        //document.getElementById('gt1').value=gt1;
    } 
</script>
```

this is work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have element with id 'gt'.

Change last line of code to this:

```
document.getElementById('gt1').value = gt1;
```

Comment: @ArghaGuhaRoy check 'Regent' answer also. Rename your gt1 function.

Comment: @aleha by the way, I'm still suprised that `gt1` function will not be excuted when there is `id="gt1"`

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code.

```
<script >
function getext3(){
    txt1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    txt2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    document.getElementById("text3").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 

function getext6(){
    txt1 = document.getElementById("text4").value;
    txt2 = document.getElementById("text5").value;
    document.getElementById("text6").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 
function getext7(){


    txt1 = document.getElementById("text3").value;
    txt2 = document.getElementById("text6").value;
    document.getElementById("text7").value = parseInt(txt1)+parseInt(txt2);

} 
</script>

Text1 : <input type="text" id="text1" value="5"> <br/>
Text2 : <input type="text" id="text2" value="2"> <br/>
Text3 : <input type="text" id="text3" value="" onclick="getext3()"> <br/>


Text4 : <input type="text" id="text4" value="7"> <br/>
Text5 : <input type="text" id="text5" value="10"> <br/>
Text6 : <input type="text" id="text6" value="" onclick="getext6()"> <br/>

Text7 : <input type="text" id="text7" value="" onclick="getext7()"> <br/>
```